# Run arbitrary Python scripts on GeoServer

Tags: python, geoserver, wps

I need to create a Web Processing service on GeoServer (2.11.2) that triggers a back-end Python script. This script should be able to utilize `requests` and other packages necessary to do the job.

I have got the wps extension and all necessary GeoScript plugins installed with GeoServer.

I followed an example as below to create a custom script that can be called from the Admin Web Console WPS Request Builder.

http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/processing/scripting/processcreate.html

```
import math, sys
from geoserver.wps import process
from geoscript.geom import Point
from geoscript.feature import Feature
from geoscript.layer import Layer

@process(
  title = 'Distance and Bearing',
  description = 'Computes Cartesian distance and bearing from features to an origin.' + str(sys.executable),
  inputs = {
    'origin': (Point, 'Origin from which to calculate distance and bearing.'), 
    'features': (Layer, 'Features to which distance and bearing should be calculated.')
  },
  outputs = {
    'result': (Layer, 'Features with calculated distance and bearing attributes.')
  }
)
def run(origin, features):

  for f in features.features():
    p = f.geom.centroid
    d = p.distance(origin)
    b = 90 - math.degrees(math.atan2(p.y - origin.y, p.x - origin.x))

    yield Feature({'point': p, 'distance': d, 'bearing': b})
```

I tried to use Python's `sys` library and print out `sys.executable` as a testing process, but the output was `NoneType`.

I also tried to import `requests` but the GeoServer logs showed requests cannot be found.

I am wondering whether arbitrary Python packages e.g. Requests can be used in a script as such supported by GeoServer WPS. Are there any limitations for Python scripts that can be triggered as Web Processing Service by GeoServer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GeoServer does not run your OS Python, but uses Jython instead, a Java version of the same language.

That comes with its own set of ported libraries and abilities. Learn more about it here:
http://www.jython.org/

Btw, the GeoServer scripting module is shipping with Jython 2.5.2